# Assign Different Type to Class Property

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have created a class to store data from API calls I am making. It returns JSON with some meta information, and then an array of data depending on the call being made. The meta information will always have the same fields, so I have created a "Root" class for this, but the data will be different depending on the call being made, so I have created different classes for each type of data, e.g. user data, company data, etc. As shown below, I currently have the "data" property set to a list of objects, but I am trying to figure out the best way to incorporate the different types of data that can be returned, since it will vary based on the call being made.

[image: Root class object]

Right now I have the data saved as a list of objects, but I would like this to change depending on what data I am receiving. Like, if I am retrieving users, I would like for it to be a list of users.

What is the ideal way to accommodate for this? The only way I can think to do it now is to create a different "Root" class for every type of data I am expecting to receive, but that doesn't feel like it should be the most concise way to do it. I was looking into making this a factory design pattern but I wasn't sure that it fit this scenario.

Comment: What about using generics and specify desired data type like `Root<User>`?

Comment: Or create an abstract class Payload, use that in the Root message instead of List<object> and derive specific responses from Payload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a generic base class:

```cs
public abstract class ApiCallResult<T>
{
    // With your properties
    // public int Limit { get; set; }
    // [...]
    //
    public IEnumerable<T> Data { get; set; }
}
```

Then define a result per api call.

```cs
public class UserApiCallResult : ApiCallResult<User>
{
}
```

Created a small working example here:
[dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/McU8Eq)